# Selenium webdriver webelemenet.isSelected() returns incorrect values

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am trying to check if the checkbox is checked or not, for this I am using isSelected.
My checkbox is a div

```
div class="mainSprite chkBox" data-dojo-attach-event="onclick:toggle" data-dojo-attach-point="chkNode"
```

I find the div with xpath and isSelected always returns false irrespective of weather the checkbox is checked or not.
I am using slenium webdriver 2.40 and FF28

Comment: `isSelected` will work on an `input` with `type="checkbox"`.  I don't think it will work in the scenario you have described.

Comment: Is this the only way                                                  ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].checked", element)

Comment: Judging from the docs, it doesn't look like the developers cared that elements that "looked" like a checkbox were considered to be a checkbox. I wouldn't either really, as there are likely many many many ways to make something look and behave like a checkbox.

Comment: Can you share some more part of you HTML code? Because as per my experience there must be a input type element to perform check operation, might be that was hidden.

Comment: <td class="valueCell">
<table id="dijit__TemplatedMixin_13" class="chkBoxCntr" widgetid="dijit__TemplatedMixin_13">
<table id="dijit__TemplatedMixin_14" class="chkBoxCntr chkBoxChecked" widgetid="dijit__TemplatedMixin_14">
<tbody>
<tr valign="top">
<td>
<div class="mainSprite chkBox" data-dojo-attach-event="onclick:toggle" data-dojo-attach-point="chkNode"/>
</td>
<td class="chkBoxLabel" data-dojo-attach-event="onclick:toggle" data-dojo-attach-point="labelNode">Always write mail in a new window</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>

Comment: +1 for Richard's comment. If this a `div` that is styled to look like a `checkbox` then either a) there is a hidden `input` somewhere holding it's true value or b) you will have to figure out, by working with your developers, how exactly the application is determining the `div` is "checked" -> you should duplicate the same logic too.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar situation. One clue is:

```
<table id="dijit__TemplatedMixin_14" class="chkBoxCntr chkBoxChecked"...
```

Using FireBug I had to check and uncheck the textbox and look at the html for what attribute for my element was different. Then I wrote a jQuery to find the difference. Below is a sample function with 2 different return statements that i've used.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<WebElement> getSelectedItems() throws InterruptedException {


        List<WebElement> list =  (List<WebElement>) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver)
                .executeScript("return jQuery.find('[class*=\"FIChecked\"]')");
        //.executeScript("return jQuery.find('[checked=\"checked\"]')");

        return list;
    }
```

Use it as a starting point and play with the search a bit. My guess is that

```
<table id="dijit__TemplatedMixin_14" class="chkBoxCntr chkBoxChecked" widgetid="dijit__TemplatedMixin_14">
```

will switch to

```
 <table id="dijit__TemplatedMixin_14" class="chkBoxCntr" widgetid="dijit__TemplatedMixin_14">
```

when the item is not selected. So calling getSelectedItems().size should equal 0 if every box was unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

If  in your case, the XPATH of the checkbox is looks like `//*[@id='XXXXX']/div[2]`.

Then the in HTML, go to the path, `//*[@id='XXXXX']/div[1]/input`. This will have `type="checkbox"`.

Use the "isSelected" method on that

But if you want to select the checkbox, you should use `//*[@id='XXXXX']/div[2]` only.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not a checkbox and a div is seems like a checkbox you need to create a customised function which will reture you boolean value on the basis of the changed attribute of div when you click on it.

In one of my case when I am clicking in this kind of div cum checkbox an additional class is adding in the class attribute  of div tag.

function will look like,

public boolean checkStatus(WebElement element,String attribute,String value){

```
if(element.getAttribute(attribute).contains(value){
return true;
}
else{
return false;
}

}
```

and call the method like

```
obj.checkStatus(ele,"class","chkTrue");
```

where "chkTrue" is the additional class added in div.

Comment: return element.getAttribute(attribute).contains(value);

Answer (score 0):

When the div checkbox is checked, it's @class, or it's ancestor's @class should change to
".. .. .*checked" class, judge on this.